# Using Script to Execute C File in Different Directory

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to C, so apologies if this is a naive question.  I have been given a script to execute C programs.  The first line has the format:

```
./directory_name program_name program_parameter_1 program_parameter_2
```

When I execute the script from a different directory I get the following error:
No such file or directory.
When I execute the script from the named directory, I get a different type of error:
directory_name is a directory.

Does someone know what the script file is trying to accomplish?

I have read about commands that change directories through script files, but they don't seem to have this format (i.e. directory name following ./), so I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the script?

Comment: Are you sure the first item is `directory_name`?  Or maybe there is a slash between that and the program name?

Answer (score 0):

If the script is presenting a different behavior depending on the directory you are running it, that means the code inside the file is referencing some dependency that is mapped from a specific location.

Why don't you check the source and learn more about what the script is doing?

Are you confused about "./"? That's how you execute a script, you don't have to worry about what kind of interpreter will process this code, that's defined in the shebang (#!).
You can read more about it here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Shell_Scripting/Hello